# How to localize DotNetBar DatePicker?

Tags: c#-4.0, datepicker, dotnetbar

How to localize the `DatePicker` component of the `DotNetBar` to show a localized Calendar?

Even when changing the input language, it still shows the English calendar.
What's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add handler for LocalizationKeys.LocalizeString static event.

Below is an example to localize the text for DateTimeInput control.

In your static void Main() method,

```
DevComponents.DotNetBar.LocalizationKeys.LocalizeString += new DotNetBarManager.LocalizeStringEventHandler(LocalizeString);

private static void LocalizeString(object sender, LocalizeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == LocalizationKeys.MonthCalendarTodayButtonText)
        {
            e.LocalizedValue = Properties.Resources.MonthCalendarTodayButtonText;
        }
        if (e.Key == LocalizationKeys.MonthCalendarClearButtonText)
        {
            e.LocalizedValue = Properties.Resources.MonthCalendarClearButtonText;
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

You can refer to official docs here. http://www.devcomponents.com/kb2/?p=523